# How can a stream be collected into a JAX-RS MultivaluedMap?

Tags: java, java-stream, jax-rs

How can a `Stream` of items be collected into a [`MultivaluedMap`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html)?  The built-in Java `Map` collectors do not work well for this purpose, since they expect to operate on the list type of the map (`K,List<V>`), rather than the type of the `MultivaluedMap` (`<K,V>`).

Comment: Question asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc are off-topic for Stack Overflow, sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ra74 — As presented, your question is easily taken for a software recommendation question.  I think it's a very valid question aside from this, and can be easily converted to one that is unlikely to be closed for this reason.  I've taken the liberty of editing the post accordingly.

Comment: If this gets reopened, I'll add this as a proper answer.  A bit of a workaround, but one solution would be to use an existing collector to a different multimap type (here's one for Guava's `Multimap`) and then transform it into a `MultivalueMap`.  Here is such a collector: `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Multimaps.toMultimap(keyFunction, valueFunction, ArrayListMultimap::create),m -> {MultivaluedHashMap<String, Integer> result = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();result.putAll(Multimaps.asMap(m));return;});`

Comment: If this gets reopened, I'll add this as a proper answer.  This will do what you're looking to do using just the `java.util.Stream` library: `Collector.of(MultivaluedHashMap::new,(multimap, input) -> multimap.add(keyFunction.apply(input), valueFunction.apply(input)),(multimap1, multimap2) -> {multimap1.putAll(multimap2);return multimap1;});`

Comment: Thanks @M.Justin, thanks for the answer. It seems I cannot reopen it

Comment: @ra74 — It requires a number of community members with sufficient privileges to [vote to reopen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).  I've cast a reopen vote, but it still needs more to be reopened.

Comment: @ra74 — I've found that even if a question is otherwise good, outright suggesting an external library gets people to close it as a software recommendation question.  I'd recommend not bringing up that angle in the future, and just describe what you're trying to accomplish without suggesting external tools.  That said, if there's a library solution to that problem, people can still respond with that suggestion, but outright asking for such a solution tends to get questions closed.

Comment: @M.Justin Now I've got it. Just I've seen many times solutions provided by a well-known libraries lika guava or apache commons and came to wrong conclusion, didn't think about it as software recommendation

Comment: @M.Justin This question has now been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Stream.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method can be used to accomplish this.  The following would create a `MultivaluedMap` from a stream and an arbitrary `keyFn` & `valueFn` [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) pair:

```java
MultivaluedMap<K, V> multimap = list.stream().collect(
        MultivaluedHashMap::new,
        (multimap, input) -> multimap.add(keyFn.apply(input), valueFn.apply(input)),
        MultivaluedMap::putAll);
```

This creates one or more multimaps using `new MultivaluedHashMap()`, adds elements to those multimaps using `MultivaluedMap.add()`, and combines those multimaps together using `MultivaluedMap.putAll()`.

The [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) Javadocs explains this method:

> Performs a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) operation on the elements of this stream. A mutable reduction is one in which the reduced value is a mutable result container, such as an `ArrayList`, and elements are incorporated by updating the state of the result rather than by replacing the result.

Since streams can be processed in parallel, multiple interim `MultivaluedMap` instances might be created, each with a subset of the `Stream`'s values included in it.  The interim multimaps would be combined into a single `MultivaluedMap` by using `putAll` to put all elements from the interim multimaps into one of the multimaps, which is then returned as the final result.

### Example

The following will create a `MultivaluedMap<Integer, String>` from a `Stream<String>`, where the key is the length of the strings, and the values were the strings themselves:

```java
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("Ant", "Ball", "Cat", "Ant", "House");
MultivaluedMap<Integer, String> stringsByLength = strings.collect(
        MultivaluedHashMap::new,
        (multimap, input) -> multimap.add(input.length(), input),
        MultivaluedMap::putAll
);
System.out.println(stringsByLength); // {3=[Ant, Cat, Ant], 4=[Ball], 5=[House]}
```